# Can't receive my gmail emails through the command line

Tags: email, gmail

so I am a new Ubuntu user and I have been trying to configure my system to send/receive emails through the command line. I'm operating on Ubuntu 19.10 and I believe I am using heirloom [mailx](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/heirloom-mailx.1.html) version 12.5 to send emails (I used many different guides and I haven't learned how to clean up my installations yet).

My problem is that I can send emails but I can not receive any emails from my Gmail inbox. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I have enabled "less secure apps" to access my gmail which has allowed me to send emails through my email address but I can not access the inbox when I type

```
mail
```

I get the following:

```
Heirloom mailx version 12.5 6/20/10.  Type ? for help.
"/var/mail/jae": 2 messages 1 unread
 O  1 Mail Delivery Syst Mon Mar  2 12:51   84/3279  Undelivered Mail 
Returned
>U  2 Mail Delivery Syst Mon Mar  2 22:35   77/2846  Undelivered Mail 
Returned
```

Answer (score 0):

Either

1) Enable [two-step authentication in Gmail](https://www.google.com/landing/2step/#tab=how-it-works), and you add an application specific password for S-nail, then use that password rather than your regular Gmail password

or

2) Enable the otherwise necessary "less secure apps" [in Gmail](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en)

a) Open your [Google Admin console](https://admin.google.com)

b) Click Security > Basic settings

c) Under *Less secure apps*, select *Go to settings for less secure apps*

d) In the subwindow, click *Enforce access to less secure apps for all users* radio button

e) Click the Save button.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have already done these steps which allowed me to send emails. However when I use the mail command I get the following:

"/var/mail/jae": 2 messages 1 unread
 O  1 Mail Delivery Syst Mon Mar  2 12:51   84/3279  Undelivered Mail Returned
>U  2 Mail Delivery Syst Mon Mar  2 22:35   77/2846  Undelivered Mail Returned

Comment: Which did you do? 1) or 2) ? Please click https://askubuntu.com/posts/1215423/edit  and add what you did into your question so others who want to help know what steps you have performed.

Comment: Thanks, I am also learning this website too. I did step 2 which allowed me to send emails. I posted in my question what I get when I type the mail command